# Stackexchange global inbox not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

I keep a bookmark to my stack exchange global profile's inbox tab. Its handy. Today, it is not working, see screenshot below:

[image]

All other tabs are working properly, see here:

[image]

What's wrong? Is it only me or everyone? Why?

P.S. The original link is https://stackexchange.com/users/3333488/awal-garg?tab=inbox and it automatically redirects me to https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/3333488/awal-garg

Comment: My global inbox is working.

Comment: But its not working for me.

Comment: No repro here, but agree it looks like a bug. What happens when you access the inbox in the top bar?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can see it in the top bar...

Comment: Weird, guess we need a dev to take a look.

Comment: Ok, just saw. A related question mentions of a private beta. I joined the Hinduism private beta this morning. But I am sure I have accessed it after joining it as well.

Comment: Update: It just started working today. Whats happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "known sites cache" on stackexchange.com hadn't yet been refreshed to include Hinduism when you received notifications about its posts and the code isn't handling that case defensively.  Once the site cache refreshed, the bug disappeared.

I'll fix up the code to refresh the cache (and not blow up the whole page for a single inbox item's issue).

Comment: Thank you so much, glad you (will) fix(ed) it :)

Comment: Won't you tag the question as `status-something`?

Comment: I will, once I fix it :)